# Question about phase portrait and invariant subspaces

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am trying to understand why the eigenvectors are the $A$ invariant subspaces of a phase portrait.

An A-invariant subspace is defined by the relation $AV \subseteq V$ where $V$ is a subspace and $A$ is some operator

Then there exist a theorem that says given a point $x_o \in V$, $e^{At}x_o \in V$

So suppose we have

[image]

Then let $x_o \in L_1$, then $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} e^{At}x_o = 0$, $0 \in L_1$, so $L_1$ is an invariant subspace..

*What about $L_2$? $x_o \in L_1$, then $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} e^{At}x_o = \infty$ (aside from $x_o = 0$). Can we say that $L_2$ is also an invariant subspace since the line extends to infinity?*

Also why are eigenvectors the only invariant subspaces? And does it matter if the eigenvector is convergent or not?

Comment: Sorry, but could you rewrite your question in more understandable fashion? Notation appears from out of the blue and it's not really clear what are you asking.

Comment: First, I think that as you draw the directions, if $x_0\in L_1$ then $\lim_{t\to-\infty}e^{At}x_0=0$, right? (note the $-\infty$). Second, the same conclusions that you have for one eigenspace, say $L_1$ are applicable to $L_2$. So they you prove invariance in one, applies the same for the other just by changing time direction. Perhaps you can give more details if this is not enough clarification.

Comment: @pepetoro No this is good. My point is, given any point on the plot, which "lines" are considered invariance subspaces? Is it only the lines that directs inward to origin (convergent)? Why are eigenvectors the only invariant subspaces, what about the other lines (not shown) on the plot?

Comment: @FemaleTank by definition all trajectories are invariant subspaces. Take any point in an orbit, take the action of the flow on that point in forward and backward time, it will give you the entire trajectory. Thus, eigenvectors are not the only invariant subspaces, however, they are important since you can obtain them explicitly without integrating the differential equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be an eigenvector of $A$, i.e. $A x = \lambda x$, then $V = \{\alpha x | \alpha \in \mathbb{C}\}$ is an $A$-invariant subspace, because $A (\alpha x) = \alpha \lambda x \in V$.

Now observe that $e^{At} x = e^{\lambda t}x$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ (Spectral Mapping Theorem). Therefore if you select $x_0 = x$, the trajectory will be in $V$ forever and it doesn't matter if it converges or not.

This is also true for all linear combinations of eigenvectors of $A$. This is why all the trajectories are also $e^{At}$-invariant.

Comment: Makes me wonder if there exist such thing as non A invariant trajectories