# Show real eigenspaces of a matrix are invariant subspaces of phase space.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm studying systems of linear differential equations and have the following problem:

> Show that real eigenspaces corresponding to the matrix $A\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ are invariant subspaces of the phase plane, i.e., for $\lambda$ eigenvalue of $A$ and $E(\lambda,A)$ it's eigenspace, if for some $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $y(t)\in E(\lambda,A)$, then $y(s)\in E(\lambda,A)$ for all $s>t$.

My attempt is the following one:

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matriz with real entries, $\lambda$ a real eigenvalue of $A$ and $E(A,\lambda)$ the corresponding eigenspace. Since $\dim(E(\lambda,A))<\dim(A)=n<\infty$, there exists $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ such that it is a basis for $E(A,\lambda)$, for some $k\leq n$.

Now fix $t\in\mathbb{R}$, if $y(t)\in E(\lambda,A)$, then there exist $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$ such that $y(t)=\sum_{j=1}^k\alpha_jv_j$.

Let's consider $s>t$. Now we have the IVP:
$$
\begin{cases}
y'=Ay, \\
y(t)=\sum_{j=1}^k\alpha_jv_j.
\end{cases}
$$
The homogeneous solution would depend on the multiplicity of the eigenvalue. However, if we consider the exponential of a matrix, $e^{Ax}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty A^kx^k/k!$, it is a fundamental matrix for the system and satisfies $\left(e^{Ax}\right)=Ae^{Ax}$. I also know, due to Lagrange Method (also known as variation of parameters) that the homogeneous solution is some multiple of $e^{(s-t)A}y_0$ (this exponential matrix satisfies common properties of the real valued function $e^x$) where $y_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is the initial condition (in our case the sum of $\alpha_jv_j$). Doing some algebraic work, I got that
$$y(s)=e^{-tA}\bar{v}$$
where $\bar{v}$ is a vector in the eigenspace, but since the matrix $e^{-tA}$ is the inverse of the fundamental matrix, it has no linearly independent solutions to the differential equation, so I cannot asure $y(s)$ is parallel to $\bar{v}$ and conclude the exercise.

I also thought about the solution using generalized eigenvectors to fully complete de space and have a more general form but that led me to nothing enlighting. Sorry if this attempt seems pretty confusing, I'm kinda lost in here.

Just in case, I know something realted has been asked here: [Question about phase portrait and invariant subspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473821/question-about-phase-portrait-and-invariant-subspaces) but I use different definitions and don't understand the answer too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier way. Note that everything is smooth, etc, so there are no issues about existence or uniqueness. Suppose $y$ is the solution to $y'=Ay$ such that passes through $y(t)$ at time $t$.

Let $x(s) = y(t) e^{\lambda (s-t)}$ and check that $x'(s) = Ax(s)$ and $x(t) = y(t)$. Since the solution is unique we have $y=x$.

Comment: I knew it was some kind of this simple stuff, I was getting lost. Thank you very much :)